# Building fine-uploader without the UI

Tags: fine-uploader

Fine uploader is 400kb of javascript code and 140kb minified. Since I am not using the UI and only using the API, I would like to build the library without the integrated interface (and hopefully get a smaller lib consequently). Is this possible?

Could not find this in the downloads section.

I've also setup the [build environment](http://docs.fineuploader.com/contributing.html) and built the package myself, but all the files in the _dist dir seem to be bundled with the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fine Uploader is only 40 kB gzipped, which is compression that pretty much every web server already utilizes. The build is not currently setup to create a bundle without the UI. If you'd like to create such a build, the [modules.js file](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/blob/5.6.0/lib/modules.js) will need to be modified. One place to start would be with a copy of the `fuTraditional` module sans the `@fuSrcUi` module. Then, a corresponding entry would need to be added to the [concat.js build file](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/blob/5.6.0/lib/grunt/configs/concat.js). This doesn't seem worth it to save a few kB in my humble opinion, but it's all very possible.

If you're interested in a much more modular upload library where almost every feature is represented as an optional standalone module, take a look at [Modern Uploader](https://github.com/FineUploader/modern-uploader), which I am slowly developing as time allows. Feel free to open up issues in the repo if you have any questions regarding the future of that product.